# How to insert data into SQLite3 database with Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to insert data into SQLite3 database using Python. I have written the query but it's not working as I expected. My code is below.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
cursor = conn.cursor()
location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
rname = request.POST.get('rname')
seat = request.POST.get('seat')
projector = request.POST.get('projector')
video = request.POST.get('video')
location_name = location_name[0:255]
rname = rname[0:255]
seat = seat[0:10]
from_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
to_date = request.POST.get('from_date')
current_datetime = datetime.datetime.now()
now = current_datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting (room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name) \ VALUES (rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name  )")

conn.commit()
```

Here I am giving the dynamic value and no data is inserting into table.

Comment: Did you try `cursor.commit()` at the end

Comment: I have written there. I think any wrong in query.

Comment: What is `conn`?

Comment: try this `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting (room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name) \ VALUES " %(rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name  ))`

Comment: @ksai The string for the SQL statement has no format specifiers to place the data from the tuple.

Comment: @ksai : Its throwing error `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the values of your variables into the SQL statement. The safest way to do this is with something like the following

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting (room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name ))
```

Note that the variables are passed as a tuple so that their values can be used in the SQL statement.

Comment: Yep and looks like he is populating all table so: **cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name ))** should be enough, right?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Code-Apprentice:

You could uses `executemany` to insert many values:

```
cursor.executemany(
  "INSERT INTO booking_meeting (room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
  [
    (rname1, from_date1, to_date1, seat1, projector1, video1, now1, location_name1),
    (rname2, from_date2, to_date2, seat2, projector2, video2, now2, location_name2)
  ]
)
```

[Furher reading](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sqlite3.html)