# Shorten SQLite3 insert statement for efficiency and readability

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-insert

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45407876/6929343):

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting (room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name ))
```

I'd like to shorten it to something like:

```
simple_insert(booking_meeting, rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name)
```

The first parameter is the table name which can be read to get list of column names to format the first section of the SQLite3 statement:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO booking_meeting (room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name)
```

Then the values clause (second part of the insert statement):

```
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
```

can be formatted by counting the number of column names in the table.

I hope I explained the question properly and you can appreciate the time savings of such a function. How to write this function in python? ...is my question.

There may already a `simple_insert()` function in SQLite3 but I just haven't stumbled across it yet.

Comment: If you're inserting into all the columns you can leave out the `(room_name,from_date,to_date,no_seat,projector,video,created_date,location_name)` part of the query; then you could just count the number of parameters to your `simple_insert` function and build the `VALUES` clause with one less `?` (to account for the parameter which is the table name)

Comment: @Nick Yes I will always be inserting all the columns into the row. I didn't know you could actually insert a row with missing columns. That seems counterintutitive.

Comment: As long as there are default values for the missing columns, or they can be `NULL`, you can insert a row with missing columns.

Comment: @Nick I could always have default value and NULL inserted. Don't see the need to define them globally. Besides my table is dynamic and there are no static fields.

Comment: @Nick If you have time to write a function and post it I would like to use it and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inserting into all the columns, then you don't need to specify the column names in the `INSERT` query. For that scenario, you could write a function like this:

```py
def simple_insert(cursor, table, *args):
    query = f'INSERT INTO {table} VALUES (' + '?, ' * (len(args)-1) + '?)'
    cursor.execute(query, args)
```

For your example, you would call it as:

```py
simple_insert(cursor, 'booking_meeting', rname, from_date, to_date, seat, projector, video, now, location_name)
```

Note I've chosen to pass `cursor` to the function, you could choose to just rely on it as a global variable instead.

Comment: Brilliant three-liner! I'm just learning python and SQL so `*args`, `query` and your `VALUES` extrapolation is above my pay grade. Quick question though since there are already two question marks shouldn't `(len(args)-1)` be `(len(args)-2)` instead?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix There needs to be `len(args)` question marks; the first part `'?, ' * (len(args)-1)` generates `len(args)-1` of them, and the `'?)'` adds the last one.

Comment: You could also use something like `', '.join('?' for _ in args)` to generate the list of question marks.

Comment: I've used the `join` command a couple of times in my program. I guess it might be more readable. I'm still back in Python 2.7.12 days if that makes any difference?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix you really should upgrade, python 2 hasn't been supported for over a year. But either code will work fine in 2.7

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS which supports Python 2.7.12 and 3.5 (I think) for a few more years. I just want to learn the legacy code first before moving to Python 4 or Python 5 or whatever in the year 2024. I'll skip all the 3.5 to 3.9 stuff I guess. Granted there is some github code published in 3.x which I have to downgrade to 2.x which is inconvient. I do use the "future" print statement, "with" statement" and "subprocess32" statement which will make migration easier when I change the first line of program from "python" to "python4" or "pythoon5" or whatever.