# Inserting an array into a database SQL Python SqLite3 without using Cursor

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to insert a 2D array into a database where the 2d array can vary. I'm using SQlite3.
USing cursor results is "NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined"

I've tried.

```
for I in range(0,t):
    mycursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Assignments (AssignmentID, StudentID, AssessmentID, Deadline, Submitted, Mark, Marked) VALUES (c[I][0],c[I][1],c[I][2],c[I][3],c[I][4],c[I][5],c[I][6])");
```

```
access_database_with_result(database,"INSERT INTO Assignments (AssignmentID, StudentID, AssessmentID, Deadline, Submitted, Mark, Marked) VALUES (c[I][0],c[I][1],c[I][2],c[I][3],c[I][4],c[I][5],c[I][6])");
```

But neither work.

```
import mysql.connector
```

Doesn't work either.

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s, %s, %s)", (var1, var2, var3))

Doesn't work due to "NameError: name 'cursor' is not defined"

Comment: Could you provide code where you have setup your connection and cursor such as in this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45407767/how-to-insert-data-into-sqlite3-database-with-python

Comment: I don't know who to set up cursors.

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the linked question does not help me.